# Run neovim as an external application in Linux

Tags: linux, vim, kde, konsole, neovim

I want to run `neovim` as an external separate program. I created a desktop file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Neovim
Comment=Run nvim in konsole with customize options
Keywords=Text;Editor;Plaintext;Write;
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
Exec=konsole --profile nvim --hide-tabbar --hide-menubar -e nvim
Type=Application
Icon=nvim
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;TextEditor;
```

Now when I run this a new `Konsole` window opens. I don't want it to be like this. It means that it should not be grouped with the other `Konsole` icons in my Task Manager and I can access it. My desktop is `KDE Plasma` and I was able to change some of the settings of this window that opens for `neovim` with Window Rules, but unfortunately, nothing more.

Comment: I've also tried to avoid grouping Konsole apps (like neovim) but I've not had any success. So in this case I used the [Kitty terminal](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty.git) and in the desktop file add something like these lines:

1. `Exec=kitty --class neovim nvim %F`
2. `StartupWMClass=neovim`
3. `Icon=nvim`

Comment: You can change `Icon=nvim` for any global icon or a custom icon path. These lines will allow the `neovim` application to run in different groups (and therefore the icon of the application would be `nvim` in this case)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon For better compatibility with Persian language, I use Konsole. I want to use this terminal as much as possible. If not, I will go to another terminal. I also changed its icon, but it didn't make a difference.